# How to append a string to each element of a Bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array in Bash, each element is a string. How can I append another string to each element? In Java, the code is something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    array[i].append("content");
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java, and don't have an append method. `cannot find symbol
symbol  : method append(java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String
      array[i].append (" content");` The simplified for-loop should slowly - after 5 years - be adopted too. `for (String s: array) System.out.println (s + " content");`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tested, and it works:

```
array=(a b c d e)
cnt=${#array[@]}
for ((i=0;i<cnt;i++)); do
    array[i]="${array[i]}$i"
    echo "${array[i]}"
done
```

produces:

```
a0
b1
c2
d3
e4
```

EDIT: declaration of the `array` could be shortened to

```
array=({a..e})
```

To help you understand arrays and their syntax in bash the [reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) is a good start. Also I recommend you [bash-hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays) explanation.

Comment: it works... but a bit confusing. can u explain what does "{}" mean, as in ${array[i]}? why not $array[$i]?

Comment: @Richard: unfortunately, the syntax required to work with bash arrays is ... arcane to put it mildly; I don't believe it can be explained _easier_ than the man-page for bash does it. (Moreover, this serves as the 'stay-away sign' for me)

Comment: `array[i]="${array[i]}$i"` can be simplified to: `array[$i]+="$i"`

Comment: Thanks, this gives me idea to append string to specific element +1

Comment: ...and this is the one that works for prefixes (prepending a string before the array elements), not just suffixes

Answer (score 144):

As mentioned by hal

```
  array=( "${array[@]/%/_content}" )
```

will append the '_content' string to each element.

```
  array=( "${array[@]/#/prefix_}" )
```

will prepend 'prefix_' string to each element

Comment: Thanks. I was actually looking for prepending a string, so your `#` addition is very useful to me.

Comment: This, succinct and to the point, should be the accepted answer. It works with any [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) and applies the manipulation to each array element.

Comment: How about append the '_content' string to each dictionary keys?

Comment: what if prepend and append same time? /%/_content/#/prefix seems doesn't work.

Comment: @ZFY: you would need to perform two passes.

Comment: This fails when an array item contains a space.

Comment: NB: If you have IFS=$'\n' (to handle names with whitespace) then the append command will not keep the original array structure. It will just make array contain only 1 item (a string list), with all the changed strings. As seen if you run: `declare -p array` afterwards.

Answer (score 112):

You can append a string to every array item even without looping in Bash!

```
# cf. http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1826
array=(a b c d e)
array=( "${array[@]/%/_content}" )
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: Good one! Is not the exact answer to the question, but is the unquestionable winner of the do-it-shorter competition! +1

Comment: The Joyent link is broken, see http://web.archive.org/web/20101114051536/http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1826 instead (Wayback Machine for that link).

Comment: Note: this does actually loop internally.

Comment: NB: If you have IFS=$'\n' (to handle names with whitespace) then the append command will not keep the original array structure. It will just make array contain only 1 item (a string list), with all the changed strings. As seen if you run: `declare -p array` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You pass in the length of the array as the index for the assignment. The length is 1-based and the array is 0-based indexed, so by passing the length in you are telling bash to assign your value to the slot after the last one in the array. To get the length of an array, your use this `${array[@]}` syntax.

```
declare -a array
array[${#array[@]}]=1
array[${#array[@]}]=2
array[${#array[@]}]=3
array[${#array[@]}]=4
array[${#array[@]}]=5
echo ${array[@]}
```

Produces

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: good answer. regrettably the required syntax (sin tax) can not be sufficiently lamented

Comment: Just reread the question and realized I answered something slightly different. I'll leave this answer here though since it still has some valuable information regarding arrays in bash.

Comment: `array+=(1)`; `array+=(2)`; ... `array+=(etc)`